# Number of permutations of $D,D,D,O,O,O,G,G,G$ such that no two $D$ are adjacent and no two $G$ are adjacent

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, solution-verification, alternative-proof, combinatorics-on-words

I have the following problem.  I already solved it but I am not happy with my solution.  I hope for a more slick solution and maybe somebody can help with it.  Is there a way to solve this problem with just the stars/bars method?

> Compute the number of ways to permute all letters from $D,D,D,O,O,O,G,G,G$ such that no two $D$ are adjacent and no two $G$ are adjacent.

**My attempt.**

For $k=2,3$, let $\Delta_k$ denote the set of permutations s.t. only $k$ of $D$ are adjacent, and let $\Gamma_k$ denote the set of permutations s.t. only $k$ of $G$ are adjacent.  Let $U$ be the set of all permutations without any conditions.

Then $$|U|=\frac{(3+3+3)!}{3!3!3!}=1680.$$  We have $$|\Delta_3|=\frac{(1+3+3)!}{1!3!3!}=140$$ (as $\Delta_3$ is the set of permutations of $DDD,O,O,O,G,G,G$), and $$|\Delta_2|+2|\Delta_3|=\frac{(1+1+3+3)!}{1!1!3!3!}=1120$$ since this number counts the permutations of $DD,D,O,O,O,G,G,G$.  Therefore $$|\Delta_2|=1120-2(140)=840.$$  Similarly $|\Gamma_3|=140$ and $|\Gamma_2|=840$.

We want to find $|\Delta_i\cap\Gamma_j|$.  Since $\Delta_3\cap\Gamma_3$ is the set of permutations of $DDD,O,O,O,GGG$, $$|\Delta_3\cap\Gamma_3|=\frac{(1+3+1)!}{1!3!1!}=20.$$  Since $|\Delta_2\cap\Gamma_3|+2|\Delta_3\cap\Gamma_3|$ counts the permutations of $DD,D,O,O,O,GGG$, we have $$|\Delta_2\cap\Gamma_3|+2|\Delta_3\cap\Gamma_3|=\frac{(1+1+3+1)!}{1!1!3!1!}=120$$ so $$|\Delta_2\cap\Gamma_3|=120-2(20)=80.$$  Similarly $|\Delta_3\cap\Gamma_2|=80$.

We now want to find $|\Delta_2\cap\Gamma_2|$.  Since $|\Delta_2\cap\Gamma_2|+2|\Delta_3\cap\Gamma_2|+2|\Delta_2\cap\Gamma_3|+4|\Delta_2\cap\Gamma_3|$ counts the number of permutations of $DD,D,O,O,O,GG,G$, we get $$|\Delta_2\cap\Gamma_2|+2|\Delta_3\cap\Gamma_2|+2|\Delta_2\cap\Gamma_3|+4|\Delta_2\cap\Gamma_3|=\frac{(1+1+3+1+1)!}{1!1!3!1!1!}=840.$$  Hence $$|\Delta_2\cap\Gamma_2|=840-2(80)-2(80)-4(20)=440.$$

By inclusion-exclusion principle we have $$|\Delta_2\cup\Delta_3\cup\Gamma_2\cup\Gamma_3|=\sum_{k=2}^3|\Delta_k|+\sum_{k=2}^3|\Gamma_k|-\sum_{i=2}^3\sum_{j=2}^3|\Delta_i\cap \Gamma_j|.$$  Therefore $$|\Delta_2\cup\Delta_3\cup\Gamma_2\cup\Gamma_3|=2(840)+2(140)-(440+80+80+20)=1340.$$  The question asks for the size of $U\setminus(\Delta_2\cup\Delta_3\cup\Gamma_2\cup\Gamma_3)$, which is $$|U|-|\Delta_2\cup\Delta_3\cup\Gamma_2\cup\Gamma_3|=1680-1340=340.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there is a slicker way to do this but it can be simpler, even using your approach.

Permutations of "DD D G G G O O O" cover all cases of adjacent D's and adjacent G's except where G's are adjacent but D's are not.

$i)$ Permutations of "DD D G G G O O O" $=  \dfrac{8!}{3!3!} - \dfrac{7!}{3!3!} = 980$

[*The subtraction is to take care of adjacent DD D and D DD considered different. So DDD permutations are counted twice and need to be taken out once.*]

$ $

$ii)$ Permutations of "GG G O O O" and placing $3$ D's in $3$ of the non-adjacent $6$ places

$$=  \dfrac{5!}{3!}.{^6}C_3 - \dfrac{4!}{3!}.{^5}C_3 = 360$$

[*The subtraction is to take care of adjacent GG G and G GG considered different. So GGG permutations and placing D in $3$ out of $5$ places have been counted twice and need to be counted out once.*]

$ $

That gives you the desired arrangements $= 1680 - 980 - 360 = 340$

Answer (score 1):

I start by restating and modifying the problem slightly, then solve it under this new
form; the passage to the initial problem is canonical.

**Problem.**
Consider the set
$S=S(d+4)=\{x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2, y_3, z_1, \ldots, z_{d-2}\}$.  A
permutation of $S$ is called $x,y$-*adjacent free* (and later of
type $(1,1)$) if no two $x$'s and no two $y$'s are adjacent.
Determine the number of $x,y$-adjacent free permutations.

1. Note that the elements $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are seen as distinct
   elements (and the same for the $y$'s).
2. The passage from **Problem** to the initial question is given by the obvious
   formula
   $$
     \frac{\text{number of $x,y$-adjacent free permutations of $S$}}
     {3!\, 3!\, (d-2)!}
   $$
   in which we take $d=3$.

The solution leans towards recursive algebraic computations (the model
being Pascal's triangle).  On the positive side, we might be happy with recursive
formulas (generalizations, computations of other similar numbers...).  On the negative side, there will be cumbersome flying indices in all directions.

**Notation and description of the solution.**
Let $S^{a,b}\subset S$ be the subset
$$
  S^{a,b} = \{ x_1,\ldots,x_a, y_1, \ldots, y_b, z_1, \ldots, z_{d-2}\}
  \subset S
$$
with $1\leq a,b\leq3$.  It has $d+a+b-2$ elements.  Denote by
$P_{(i,j)}^{a,b}$, with $i\leq a$ and $j\leq b$, the set of permutations of
$S^{a,b}$ with exactly $i$ adjacent $x$'s and $j$ adjacent $y$'s,
called *permutations of type* $(i,j)$.
Clearly the set of all permutations of $S^{a,b}$ is
$$
  \bigcup_{\substack{1\leq i\leq a\\1\leq j\leq b}}
  P_{(i,j)}^{a,b}.
$$
We want to compute $N_{(1,1)}^{3,3}$, the cardinal of
$P_{(1,1)}^{3,3}$.  The idea is to do the computation recursively using
the following filtration of $S^{3,3}$:
$$
  S^{1,1} \subset S^{2,1} \subset S^{3,1}
  \subset S^{3,2} \subset S^{3,3}.
$$
Each $N_{(i,j)}^{a,b}$ corresponding to the subset $S^{a,b}$ in the
filtration is expressed as a linear combination with integer
coefficients of all the $N$'s of the previous subset.  Once the
coefficients are determined (using the combinatorics of the
construction) for all these passages, the problem is solved.

**Finding the coefficients.**
Let's start with what we are looking for:
$$
  N_{(1,1)}^{3,3} = d\,N_{(1,1)}^{3,2} + N_{(2,1)}^{3,2}.
$$
The other coefficients are all zero in this case.  The explanation is
that a permutation of $S^{3,3}$ of type $(1,1)$ can only be issued
from a permutation of $S^{3,2}$ which is either of type $(1,1)$ or of
type $(2,1)$.  For a permutation in the former case, there are
exactly $d=d+4-4$ positions (out of $d+4$) where $y_3$ can be inserted
(adjacent to neither $y_1$ nor $y_2$).  In the latter case, $y_3$ must
be inserted in-between the two adjacent $x$'s.

We pursue with the formulas for $N_{(1,1)}^{3,2}$ and $N_{(2,1)}^{3,2}$
using the passage from $S^{3,1}$ to $S^{3,2}$ in our filtration.  The
formula for $N_{(1,1)}^{3,2}$ is almost the same as the previous one:
$$
  N_{(1,1)}^{3,2} = (d+3-2)\,N_{(1,1)}^{3,1} + N_{(2,1)}^{3,1}
  = (d+1)\,N_{(1,1)}^{3,1} + N_{(2,1)}^{3,1}.
$$
The formula for $N_{(2,1)}^{3,2}$ is trickier.  It reads
$$
  N_{(2,1)}^{3,2}
  = 0\,N_{(1,1)}^{3,1} + (d+3-3)\,N_{(2,1)}^{3,1} + 2N_{(3,1)}^{3,1} \\
  = d\,N_{(2,1)}^{3,1} + 2N_{(3,1)}^{3,1}.
$$
The coefficient $d+3-3$ comes form the following observation: If a
type $(2,1)$ permutation of $S^{3,2}$ is issued form a type $(2,1)$
permutation of $S^{3,1}$, then $y_2$ has exactly $d+3-3$ possible
places to be inserted in: $d+3$ is the total number of places and $y_2$ can take
neither the place in-between the adjacent $x$'s nor any of the two places adjacent to
$y_1$.

Looking at the last two formulas, we note that from now on we need all
the $N$'s corresponding to the remaining subsets of the filtration.
But they are fewer and the formulas easier to figure out.  We obtain
successively:

- for $S^{2,1}\subset S^{3,1}$
  $$
    N_{(1,1)}^{3,1} = (d+2-4)\,N_{(1,1)}^{2,1} + 0\,N_{(2,1)}^{2,1}
  $$
  $$
    N_{(2,1)}^{3,1} = 4\,N_{(1,1)}^{2,1} + (d+2-3)\,N_{(2,1)}^{2,1}
  $$
  $$
    N_{(3,1)}^{3,1} = 0\,N_{(1,1)}^{2,1} + 3\,N_{(2,1)}^{2,1}
  $$
- for $S^{1,1}\subset S^{2,1}$
  $$
    N_{(1,1)}^{2,1} = (d+1-2)\,N_{(1,1)}^{1,1}
    \quad\text{and}\quad
    N_{(2,1)}^{2,1} = 2\,N_{(1,1)}^{1,1}.
  $$

**The computations**
Now, to obtain $N_{(1,1)}^{3,3}$ it is sufficient to go backward
starting with $N_{(1,1)}^{1,1}=d!$.  Let's perform the computations by
stressing their algorithmic character.  I hope the notation below is
self-explanatory.

1. For $S^{2,1}$:
   $$
   \begin{array}{c||c|cr}
     & (1,1) && result/d! \\ \hline
     (1,1) & d-1 && (d-1) \\
     (2,1) & 2 && 2
   \end{array}
   $$
2. For $S^{3,1}$:
   $$
   \begin{array}{c||c|c|cr}
     & (1,1) & (2,1) && result/d! \\ \hline
     (1,1) & d-2 & 0 && (d-2)(d-1) \\
     (2,1) & 4 & d-1 && 6(d-1) \\
     (3,1) & 0 & 3 && 6
   \end{array}
   $$
3. For $S^{3,2}$ (partial table):
   $$
   \begin{array}{c||c|c|c|cr}
     & (1,1) & (2,1) & (3,1) && result/d! \\ \hline
     (1,1) & d+1 & 1 & 0 && (d-1)(d^2-d+4) \\
     (2,1) & 0 & d & 2 && 6(d^2-d+2)
   \end{array}
   $$
4. So
   $$
     \begin{split}
     N_{(1,1)}^{3,3}
     &= d\,N_{(1,1)}^{3,2} + N_{(2,1)}^{3,2} \\
     &= \big( (d^2-d)(d^2-d+4) + 6(d^2-d+2) \big)\,d! \\
     &= \big( (d^2-d)^2 + 10(d^2-d) + 12 \big)\,d! \\
     &= \big( (d^2-d+4)(d^2-d+6) - 12 \big)\,d!.    
     \end{split}
   $$

In particular, the answer to the initial question is
$$
  \frac{(5^2-5+4)(5^2-5+6)-12}{3!\,3!}\,\frac{5!}{3!}
  = 20\,\frac{2\cdot26-1}{3} = 340.
$$